# How to move screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I am making a little game project and am struggling to make the screen follow whenever the character moves. For more detail, there are buttons with directions, when clicked the player (widget class) moves, and then it's far enough from middle, the screen should follow (the main struggle part).

Example:

'''

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MainWin>:
    Button:
        text: "left"
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.08)
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "y": 0.1}
        on_press: root.move("left")
''')


class MainWin(FloatLayout):
    def move(self, direction):
        #when button is clicked
        #all objects besides character moves the opposite way
        pass
        


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWin()

MainApp().run()
```

'''

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added it. Hope it's enough.

Comment: you need to think about what needs to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RelativeLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html) instead. Then if you move the layout, the widgets inside will move. The children of FloatLayout use absolute position, when RelativeLayout's children, use relative position as the name implies.

Comment: Thanks! I guess i got comfortable with float layout that i didn't look at other layouts at all.

Comment: you are welcome